# Is this matrix similar to some real diagonal matrix, and if is find that diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

So this is the given matrix

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

I could simply just work out characteristic polynomial to find eigenvalues and then look for eigenvectors, and if i could find six linearly independent eigenvectors that would be it. But this approach is very time consuming when i am working with 6x6 matix. So i am looking for a way to solve this differently. So far, i noticed that trace is zero, columns of this matrix are orthogonal, in fact they are orthonormal, meaning that this is orthogonal matrix, and that columns are linearly independent, so dimension of image is 6, which means that nullity is zero (so zero isn't eignenvalue), but i found out that row sum is same for every row and it is equal to one, so that's one of the eigenvalues and corresponding vector is $$x_1= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\\1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix} $$ but i can't tell if that's only linearly independent vector that corresponds to eigenvalue 1 , since i don't even know algebraic multiplicity of it. Am i not seeing something about this matrix that would simplify my work?

Comment: It is a stochastic matrix, that means at least one eigenvector will be corresponding to eigenvalue 1 and all the rest of the eigenvalues will have largest possible modulus 1.

Comment: Have you noticed that you can express your matrix as block-diagonal ($4 \times 4$ and $2 \times 2$). Thus naturally your characteristic polynomiall will be a product... Moreover it is a permutation matrix.

Comment: We have $A^4 = I$ so the only possible eigenvalue will be with absolute values 1 since raised to 4 they will all be 1 because that is what the identity matrix has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a permutation matrix. It acts on the usual basis
of column vectors as $e_1\mapsto e_3\mapsto e_4\mapsto e_2\mapsto e_1$
and $e_5\mapsto e_6\mapsto e_5$. It corresponds to the permutation
 $(1\,3\,4\,2)(5\,6)$. This has cycles of lengths $4$ and $2$, and the
matrix eigenvalues are therefore the fourth roots of unity (and the second roots of unity again). So $i$ is an eigenvalue and the matrix is not
diagonalisable over $\Bbb R$ (although it is over $\Bbb 
C$).